# Change PHP version in Centos 7

Tags: php, centos7

Currently, I am running Centos 7 on my machine and when I installed PHP on my machine I was able to use only the default version of PHP. For example, executing command "*yum install php*" install's PHP of version 5.4. Some of my application requires PHP version 5.4, some require PHP 5.6. Is there any way to change the PHP version without installing the required version all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this with yum, but you could compile your own versions and keep them separated by changing the `--prefix` setting during configuration.

```
% cd /path/to/php-5.4/source
% ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php-5.4

% cd /path/to/php-5.6/source
% ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php-5.6
```

That said, it would be a real pain, as you'd have to muck with your PATH to prefer one over the other in the shell, and create two separate FPM configurations for your web server. I would recommend instead either running two separate servers or run your applications in Docker containers (which are pretty trivial to launch with an exact spefic version.)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the command:
sudo yum install mod_php70u
 to install a php 7.  Usually, a higher version will cover requirements in lower version.

Comment: Not on CentOS, you can't…

Comment: The OP also isn't looking for PHP 7. They want to interchange between 5.4 and 5.6.